# Garbage collection minimization. Will someone clarify something about iterators?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, iterator

I'm an Android noob. I am having trouble with this statement:

> Avoid using iterators as they create new objects.

What exactly is an iterator? I thought it was this:

```
    int a = 1;
    while (a < 100)
        System.out.println(a);
        a += 1;  //iterator
```

The key here is garbage collection. Is this a problem because each time a loop cycles, a new instance of a is created in memory? I cannot think of a way to do something like this otherwise. Maybe creating an object for "a" that holds "a" and having an add(int something) method and a getA() method.

How would I do this otherwise (if possible)? Am I missing something?

Comment: 'a' is defined above the loop and is only being re-assigned per loop iteration. An Iterator is an interface in Java/Android core API

Comment: Do you realize that the code you've printed will loop forever? You need braces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, that is not `Iterator`. That is Iteration. [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is interface in Java/Android API

2) `int` is primitive type, not `Object` type, so it will be allocated on stack than heap. As soon as method call done, stack will go.

3) Even though you create new object inside loop with reference variable inside loop, that reference will be scoped to loop. As soon as loop completes, reference will be gone and object will be eligible for GC.